# How is a plus-minus sign evaluated in an exponent?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

When faced with an exponent containing a $\pm$, how is it handled/simplified?

For example, this expression:
$$e^{\pm i\omega\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t}\qquad(1)$$

Expands to:
$$ c_1\,e^{i\omega\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t}+c_2\,e^{-i\omega\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}t} \qquad (2)$$

And this becomes:
$$ A\,cos(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega t)+B\,sin(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega t)\qquad (3)$$

However, it is unclear to me how the $\pm$ sign led to this breakdown from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and how it was further broken down with the Euler identity and arbitrary constants into $(3)$.

What steps happened in-between expressions to progressively massage these terms, and how are they explained/justified?

---

P.S.: If anyone is wondering, these terms came from part of a solution of a 
second-order homogeneous linear differential equation in a vibrations/structural dynamics textbook.

Comment: This is to do with a family of solutions - the general solution can be written as a linear combination of the two solutions obtained by the $+$ and $-$ cases. As for the last step, why don't you try to do it yourself? Use Euler's identity on the two terms of $(2)$

Comment: IOW, "this expression" does not "expand to" that one. Rather, one should understand what the text says.

Comment: @JihoonKang, thank you for the elucidation regarding the linear combination of solutions. As for the last step, I did attempt it and ended up with an unsatisfying answer (B is imaginary) and lacked the skill to verify its correctness. $A=c_1+c_2$, $B=i (c_1-c_2)$ is as far as I got. The example solutions for A and B in the text are both real numbers.